# Combinatorics: complete set of solution to the congruence

Tags: combinatorics, congruences

$$111x \equiv 112 \bmod 113$$

I've tried all the theorems. The only thing I found is that there is only one solution. Other than trying all 1-113 possible values that x takes, is there any efficient way to do it?

Comment: (Also, fwiw, this looks like number theory, not combinatorics)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use negative numbers. We have $111\equiv -2\pmod{113}$ and $112\equiv -1\pmod{113}$.

Thus we want $-2x\equiv -1\pmod{113}$, that is, 
$2x\equiv 1\equiv 114\pmod{113}$. That gives $x\equiv 57\pmod{113}$.

Comment: Good reminder! One more question what allow you to go from -2x is equivalent to -1 to 2x is equivalent to 1

Comment: In general, if $d$ and $m$ are relatively prime, we have $dx\equiv da\pmod{m}$ if an only if $x\equiv a\pmod{m}$ (multiply by the inverse of $d$ modulo $m$). The case $d=-1$ is simplest. Concretely, in our case, $113$ divides $(-2x)-(-1)=-(2x-1)$ if and only if $113$ divides $2x-1$